# How do I make my CSS dropdown menu color scheme differentiate from the body color scheme?

Tags: html, css

So, my newer index is [here](http://www.substructures.us/index3.html), but the DropDown link list(when you hover over the link **stuff** you will see it) on the blog portion of my website which is [here](http://blog.substructures.us) does not change. Any help would be nice. This is the menu bar for my website with the link list that is set up as a widget, since it's a blogger blog attached to the website itself:

```
<style type="text/css">
ul{
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0px;
padding: 150px;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: transparent;
position: absolute;
top: -79px;
left: -703.8px;
width: 940px;
font-size:19px;
font-family: Geo;
}

li {
float: left;
text-align: center;
color: #FF733B;
background-color: transparent;
}

li a {
float: left;
display: block;    
padding: 20px;
color: #F2F2F2;
transition: .5s;
text-decoration: none;
background-color: transparent;
}

.dropbtn {
background-color: transparent;
color: #efefef;
padding: auto;
font-size: 12px;
border: none;
cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
float: left;
display: relative;
font-color: #000;
}

.dropdown-content {
display: none;
position: fixed;
background-color: #f9f9f9;
min-width: 260px;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
top: 65px;
z-index: 4;
}

.dropdown-content a {
color: #000;
padding: 8px 10px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
transition: .4s;
background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
background-color: transparent;
}
</style>
<p align="center">
<div class="table">
<ul>
<li><a href="http://www.substructures.us/index.html">Home</a></li><li><a href="http://www.substructures.us/data.html">DATA</a></li><li><a href="http://www.substructures.us/about.html">About</a></li><div class="dropdown">
<li class="dropbtn"><li><a href="http://www.substructures.us/stuff.html">Stuff</a></li>
<div class="dropdown-content">
<a href="http://www.substructures.us/nightcore-creator.html">NIGHTCORE Creator</a>
<a href="http://www.substructures.us/artwork.html">Artwork</a>
<a href="http://blog.substructures.us/">BLOG</a>
</div></li></div></ul></div></p>
<a href="http://www.substructures.us/index.html"><img style="float: right; margin: -69.9px -8.5px 0px 75px; height: 125.5%; width: 125.5%;" src="http://www.substructures.us/substructures2.png" /></a>
```

Comment: `.sidebar .widget a:link {
    color: #F2F2F2;  
    text-decoration: none;
}
`This is your problem

Comment: Nevermind. All good! Thanks.

Comment: you can use flexbox for that. So you set `display: flex` to `ul` and set the rest below. If you want to know more about flexbox, read this article: [css-tricks flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)
`ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
`